# Divs dropdown to behave like select or combo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I have a few divs in one wrapper div and all of them represents the one entity, look at image 1.

[image: Image1]

When I click on the Select 1 or Select 2 .... I need to open some kind of a dropdown list from which I need to chose option and change value of Select, but this dropdown list must be identical in design with Select div items, look at image 2.

[image: Image2]

I looked at a lot of jquery select plugins and I did not find the one.
Can anyone give me some idea how I could do this or if know a plugin that could resolve this.

This is html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <style>
            .wrapper
            {
                width:330px;
                overflow:hidden; 
                border:solid 1px gray; 
                padding: 3px;                
            }
            .element
            {
                width:80px; 
                min-height: 30px; 
                border:solid 1px black; 
                background-color: orange; 
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 30px;                
            }
            .float-left
            {
                float: left;
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="element float-left">
                Select 1
            </div>
            <div class="element float-left">                
                Select 2                
            </div>
            <div class="element float-left">
                Select 3
            </div>            
            <div class="element float-left">
                Select 4
            </div>            
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch this tutorial: [Simple Dropdown](http://www.hybridplanet.co.in/tutorial/css/simple-css-dropdown-menu-without-javascript)

UPDATE (if want to open through jquery):

Remove this css in my example:

```
 .main_nav > li:hover .sub_nav{
        background-color:#E4E4E4;
        display:block;
    }
```

and use jquery:

```
    $(".main_nav > li").click(function(){
           $(' .sub_nav').show();
          $(this).find('.sub_nav').show();
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Ashish. 
This example is classic html menu. I don't need menu option in my entity. In menu, when click on Option element, link go somewhere.
I need different functionality, when click to Option element to change the value in the Select div and nothing more, same behaviour like a combo or select.

Comment: ok, then what you do, In my given example's CSS remove or comment this line:

 .main_nav > li:hover .sub_nav{
            background-color:#E4E4E4;
            display:block;
        }

and use jquery:

$(".main_nav > li").click(function(){
$(' .sub_nav').show(); //close any opened menu
$(this).find(' .sub_nav').show(); //open selected menu
})

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me a lot! :) This is something that I can use. I will add this piece of code 
`$(".sub_nav > li").click(function () {alert("Option clicked! :)");});`
and this is the answer! Thans again. Live long and prosper! @Ashish Panwar

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know about the Jquery libraries. 
[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/1pgex515/). I think  you can get an idea from this. Do some changes you will able to do your job

```
 <style>
    .wrapper
    {
        width:330px;
        overflow:hidden; 
        border:solid 1px gray; 
        padding: 3px;                
    }
    .element
    {
        width:80px; 
        min-height: 30px; 
        border:solid 1px black; 
        background-color: orange; 
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;                
    }
    .float-left
    {
        float: left;
    }            
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element float-left">
        Select 1
    </div>
    <div class="element float-left">                
        Select 2
        <div class='options'>
            <div class='element'>Option 1</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 2</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 3</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 4</div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="element float-left">
        Select 3
        <div class='options'>
            <div class='element'>Option 1</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 2</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 3</div>
            <div class='element'>Option 4</div>
        </div>  
    </div>            
    <div class="element float-left">
        Select 4
    </div>            
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".options").slideUp(0);
    $(".element").click(function(){
        $(".options").hide(0);
        $(this).find('.options').slideDown(100);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajitha for your response. Your answer is very similar to answer of  Ashish Panwar, which is a complete solution. Look at his link. Thanks again for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

just because i don't like any jqwery, here is some solution by pure js. actually, it isn't quite finished and throws some error, but you can fix it as you like

```js
var Ready = function(){
  var menu = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  var elementsList = menu.querySelectorAll('.container');
  var toggleSubmenu = function(e){
    var current = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.submenu');
    for(var i=elementsList.length; i--;){
      var element = elementsList[i].querySelector('.submenu');
      if (element!==current && element.classList.contains('opened'))
        element.classList.remove('opened');
    }
    current.classList.toggle('opened');
  };
  menu.addEventListener('click', toggleSubmenu);
};
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', Ready );
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select, .option {
  width: 80px;
  min-height: 30px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  float: left;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.opened {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="select">Select 1</div>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="option">Option 1</div>
          <div class="option">Option 2</div>
          <div class="option">Option 3</div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="select">Select 2</div>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="option">Option 1</div>
          <div class="option">Option 2</div>
          <div class="option">Option 3</div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="select">Select 3</div>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="option">Option 1</div>
          <div class="option">Option 2</div>
          <div class="option">Option 3</div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="select">Select 4</div>
        <div class="submenu">
          <div class="option">Option 1</div>
          <div class="option">Option 2</div>
          <div class="option">Option 3</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```